# SqlConnection error:50

Tags: asp.net-core, dbcontext, sqlconnection

I get this error when PM> Update-Database

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. Cannot create an automatic instance. See the Windows Application event log for error details.

My Conection code is here:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add framework services.

        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
        services.AddSession();
        var connection = @"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=MVCLoginDB;Trusted_Connection=True;";
        services.AddDbContext<OurDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
        services.AddMvc();
    }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you browse the database with the VS Server Explorer?

Comment: have you found any details in Windows Application event log?